# Sending mail in drupal site

Tags: drupal-7, scheduler, rules

I am using drupal 7 site,In a user profile I have start and end date, I want to send the mail to user every once in a month based on the end date, end date also need to get updated based on the start date every months from current date [start date],please can anyone help me on this! it will be great helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you clarify, what you've done till now?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own module, than you should use the [hook_cron()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) where you will get all users and will check the the needed field (f.e. the end date), after when you will have all users which should get email you can use function [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) and also if you need you can implement [hook_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) in your module.